# Testing DB content, Zooming in on 1 value

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a SQLite database that returns 1 number to

`Select value from Income where symbol = "AE" and statementitem = "Revenues" and periodtype = "Annual"  and yearmonth = "Dec 2019";` --1811.2

[image]

I use a bit of c# code to test this to make sure nothing is missed:

```
    public string GetIncome(string dbFile, string symbol, string aq, string yearmonth)
    {
        var answer = String.Empty;

        try
        {
            using (var con = new SQLiteConnection($"URI=file:{dbFile}"))
            {
                con.Open();
                using var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(con)
                {
                    CommandText = $"Select value from Income where symbol = '{symbol}' and statementitem = 'Revenues' and periodtype = '{aq}'  and yearmonth = '{yearmonth}';"
                };

                using SQLiteDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    answer = dataReader.GetString(1);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }


        return answer;
    }
```

This errors out with `System.IndexOutOfRangeException : Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

Whats the best way to pick up on that value please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See official docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitedatareader.getstring?view=msdata-sqlite-3.1.0#Microsoft_Data_Sqlite_SqliteDataReader_GetString_System_Int32_

It tells that `GetString` only argument is "The zero-based column ordinal". In your case you're trying to access second item (by index 1), but your query has only single field returned. Use index 0 in

```
answer = dataReader.GetString(0);
```